# How to test scheduling algorithms for parallel realtime task-models on multiprocessor

Tags: parallel-processing, scheduled-tasks, real-time, simulator

I do research on scheduling of parallel real-time tasks. I have some theories and need a possibility to test and play around with them. I found some simulators but the most are outdatet already or have a spare documentation. Does someone know any simulator or framework i can use for my use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that with starpu task based runtime one can implement its own scheduler and that execution can be simulated with simgrid, is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thank you. SimGrid looks interesting as StarPU is too much hardware-specific to me. Do you know something more abstract or out-of-the-box? I found DLsim in some papers but it is a logic simulator for CPU "building". So i will have first to "build" a CPU before i can even try to schedule something.